# Setting process priority everytime it is launched?

Tags: windows-xp, performance

My work computer experiences a lot of slowdown, so I want to do what I can to make sure the stuff I need to be response actually is responsive.  For example, I run Pidgin, which loads everytime I boot.  How can I tell Windows XP to always set its thread priority to low?

Using the SysInternals utility 'Process Explorer', I can temporarily set the priority - until the next time the application is restarted.  How do I effectively make this permanent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Option 1

There is [Prio](http://www.prnwatch.com/prio.html). Prio extends the Windows standard TaskManager and adds a "Save priority" option to the "Set Priority" menu.

*caveat #1*: I used it a while ago (under Win-XP) and it worked fine, but I did not test it extensively.

*caveat #2*: Reason for deinstalling was licensing because:

> Prio - is distributed as freeware for personal use only. This means: 
>   All copyrights to Prio are exclusively owned by O&K Software Ltd. 
>   The program is free for personal use only. 
>   The business license has the cost $19.95 USD.

(quote from their website)

### Option 2

I found [ProcessTamer](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/proctamer/index.html) which may also help with your problem (maybe even more so). It seems to be freeware - the author just likes you to register for a free license key (otherwise a few nag windows pop up).

### Option 3

If you want this only for a few select programs, you can create a batchfile that does not call it directly but indirectly via [`start`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true) (the Windows command shell built-in) and then use that batchfile (a shortcut to it).

`start` can be used with the following options that set the process priority:

- /LOW
- /NORMAL
- /HIGH
- /REALTIME
- /ABOVENORMAL
- /BELOWNORMAL

Comment: Nice answers. For pidgin, you should just be able to change the shortcut to [cmd /c start /low "" "C:\Program Files\Pidgin\pidgin.exe"]. You need the empty quotes to indicate to start that the command-line isn't the title.

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to mark as answered.  Please know that it was oversight and not neglect.

Answer (score 6):

> Changing the application shortcut to
>   'start /low [program.exe]' should work
>   for you.

This technically can work for things that don't start automatically.  If you want it for a startup program, you can do this to the shortcut and put it into the StartUp folder obviously.  If I wanted to run:
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\dev_dir"
I would have to:

**1) Set "Start in" to the folder the actual executing file** (TortiseProc.exe in this example) is located so: "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin"

2) **Set the target to run CMD w/ "/C" to run the string following "/C" then exit, then use that to run START /PRIORITY [executable] [parameters].**  In my case, I used the following:

%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /C start /BELOWNORMAL TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\dev_dir"

%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe *Starts the command prompt*

/C *executes the following code,*

start /BELOWNORMAL TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\dev_dir" *actually starts the program given that you correctly "Start in" to the directory where the executable is located.*

Hopefully that helps somebody.

Answer (score 6):

[ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) allows priorities to be set and saved for individual processes:

[image]

> Process Hacker was started in 2008 as an open source alternative to programs such as Task Manager and Process Explorer.

**Licence: GNU General Public License version 3.0 GPLv3**

Answer (score 1):

**[Process Lasso](http://www.bitsum.com/prolasso.php)** can force priorities (and CPU affinity) to processes, along with other features like ProBalance (Process Balance):

> intelligently adjusts the priorities of running programs so that badly behaved processes won't substantially impact the responsiveness of your PC.

It's free for home usage, with a few nagscreens, 14.95$ to register the Pro license.

Answer (score 1):

I have a a way of starting a program in a specific priority in windows 7 and 8 and it takes alot less work than messing in the command prompt which is not natural for the average user.

First create a shortcut to the program. Right click your shortcut and select properties,, once the properties window opens do the following:

Before change the target line should look something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Ubisoft\Assasins Creed 3\AC3SP.exe"
```

Change it too read

```
cmd /c start/high "C:\Program Files\Ubisoft\Assasins Creed 3\AC3SP.exe"
```

and click ok.

Now you have a shortcut that will start in high priority every time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a stubborn application that is resetting its priority after being launched, the start /option answers above won't work.

I found the following info about a command line application already built into windows which can be executed on any running process.  And, yes, it does work all the way back to XP when used as follows:

```
wmic process where name="program_name.exe" CALL setpriority PriorityLevelID
```

where PriorityLevelID is:

```
Priority  
Level ID  Meaning
========  ============
  256     Realtime
  128     High
 32768    Above normal
   32     Normal
 16384    Below normal
   64     Low
```

You can create a batch file to start the program like this:

```
start "drive:path\program_name.exe"
wmic process where name="program_name.exe" CALL setpriority PriorityLevelID
```

Reference: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/89548-set-cpu-process-priority-applications-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to change the start options for the program.
You can see that setting the priority of a process at the time of invocation.

Changing the application shortcut to 'start /low [program.exe]' should work for you.

Comment: True but inconvenient, especially with automatically started processes.

Comment: can't add that in a shortcut

Comment: -1 for wrong detail about application shortcut