# Can Windows 8 use two hard drives for better speed?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd

I am doing some drive intensive work with my computer which can take several hours (generating map tiles with TileMill and PostGIS). While these tasks run my disk IO maxes out at 100%. As a result my computer grinds to a halt and I can barely execute other programs.  (CPU and RAM are not maxed out at the time, only the IO is)

Q: Is there a way to solve this by getting Windows 8 to use two hard drives?
Q:  Should I set up a RAID array ?

Currently got a 128 GB SSD with Windows 8 installed and a 500 GB internal drive. My workspace for these programs is already on the SSD.

Comment: It's highly ill advised to use RAID with two different Storage devices. How big are the files your working with? RAM disk will give you the best performance but there are so many factors to consider here.

Comment: Things to consider as Bottle necks: CPU, GPU, RAM, Storage media and junk processes

Comment: If the SSD is not giving you the throughput that you need, either look at RAID0/10 of SSD drives or look into RAMDisks (which may require a lot more ram and a lot of times is volatile if you suddenly lose power.)

Comment: My database is around 40 GB (10 million polygons).  So it exceeds my RAM.  I'm not sure I can simplify the geometry without running into problems at higher resolutions.

Comment: @AaronKreider Move your work space to the SSD and run your job - if it's still freezing you might have to look at performance (under taskmanager) and confirm you CPU or RAM isn't at 100%

Comment: My work space is on the SSD.  The problem might be that TileMill is causing 5-8 PostGreSQL processes which combined make the drive run at 100%.  This situation is sporadic. Sometimes I can run other programs, but other times I cannot.  The CPU and RAM are both far under 100%.

Comment: Is there a program similar to `ionice` for a modern windows installation? I know [there is none for XP](http://superuser.com/questions/557629/how-can-i-limit-the-disk-i-o-priority-for-a-process-in-windows-xp), but win7 and vista SP1 do have more functionality. (E.g. think of the pre-loading of files and the skipping of pre-loading during boot). My Google-fu failed me on this.

Comment: Please post the motherbaord and type of drive.  If it is a Sata 3 drive, you might **already be maxing out the total disk bandwidth for your system**.

Comment: I've got a Dell Inspiron 530.  Motherboard is: Dell/FoxConn DG33m03/0FM586.   Drive is: Intel 330 120 GB SATA 6 Gb/s 
Though I'm also considering a new computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to solve this by getting Windows 8 to use two hard drives?

It depends on why the computer grinds to a halt. If TileMill and PostGIS max out your CPU then it will not help. If they just tie up to disk with high IO then adding a second data disk and storing all data for TileMill and PostGIS are working on on the second disk will help. Your original disk would be free for other requests.

> Note: I have no experience with using a RAID. Should I set one up?

If your programs do a lot of reading then you can use RAID 1 to increase reading speed up to double that of a single disk. (Assuming identical drives for simplicity). Write speed will not increase with RAID 1.

For more information about RAID level see [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them).

> I'd like at least one of the hard drives to be SSD. I've currently got a 128 GB SSD with Windows 8 installed and a 500 GB internal drive.

You can use RAID on drives with different speeds and different sizes. However an SSD is likely to be much faster than a HDD and the gain would be rather small.