# Change default priority for an exe (every time the program is launched)

Tags: windows-7, windows, process, priority

I have a big image manipulation program that runs slow and that I am used to run with no other apps. I want to permanently set the exe to run at a higher priority.

I could run it through a batch file that would look like

```
cmd /c start/high %APP%
```

but I am looking for a cleaner way to do that, like a file property. I use win7

**Note: ** I know this question has been posted and partially answered for winXP on [Setting process priority everytime it is launched?](https://superuser.com/questions/65108/setting-process-priority-everytime-it-is-launched) ; things should have evolved.

**Note: ** Is there a third party app-launcher that would give me such options?

Comment: PS: Any opinion on Prio - Priority saver (http://www.prnwatch.com/prio/) ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any alternatives not listed in the previous question you mentioned, except maybe AutoHotkey..

AutoHotkey provides a simple way to launch applications using the Process method. You can also set the priority when you launch your app. See [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Process.htm) for details. Here's a simple example (from memory and untested):

StartNotepadInHighPriority.ahk

```
Process Wait, Notepad.exe, 10
if %ErrorLevel% = 0
{
    MsgBox Notepad did not start within 10 seconds..
    Return
}
Process Priority, , High
```

At least the nice thing about launching a shortcut to the AHK script instead of the DOS start command is there won't be a command prompt window flashing up and/or showing on the taskbar..

Comment: You could use a **batch to exe** converter to create a hidden application out of the batch file with the start command to hide the flashing up command window.